# Negativity of a function

Tags: functions

If f(x)=px^2+2px-5 , (x is real) what are the requirements for f(x), to be f(x)<0  ?

Here we can simplify the function as,
f(x)=p(x^2+2x+5/p)
      =p[(x+1)^2 - { (p+5)/5 ]

so is the requirement for f(x) to be,f(x)<0 is???

```
   p<0
```

or  (x+1)^2 <[(p+5)/p] ??

Comment: can you say something to the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  it is given that "x" is real,but nothing specific about "p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to solve $$px^2+2px-5<0$$ if $p=0$ then your inequality is true. Now we consider two cases:
A) $$p>0$$ then we have $$x^2+2x-\frac{5}{p}<0$$ and this is equivalent to
$$(x+1)^2<1+\frac{5}{p}$$ and this can be written as $$|x+1|<\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{p}}$$
for $$x\geq -1$$ we have $$x<-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{p}}$$
in the other case we get
$$x>-1-\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{p}}$$
for B) $$p<0$$ then we have $$(x+1)^2>1+\frac{5}{p}$$
if $$1+\frac{5}{p}\le 0$$ then our inequality is true.
in the othere case we get
$$|x+1|>\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{p}}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Sure I can...Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

By completing the square, $$px^2+2px-5=p(x+1)^2-5-p.$$

Then $p$ may certainly not be positive (as $(x+1)^2$ is unbounded) and the expression achieves the global maximum $-5-p$ for $x=-1$. This is negative for

$$-5<p\le0.$$

Comment: Yeah... I got it..Thanks a lot!